# Linux PHP Webserver + Apache or Nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I'm close to finishing a site and need to decide what web server to use.

The site uses PHP very heavily - every page has a lot of PHP on it.

I've read that Nginx is faster for static pages but there are questions about its performance with PHP compared to Apache's performance with PHP.

Does anyone have any comments on which web server I should work with.

thx

Comment: Just choose the one you familiar with

Comment: exactly. you can always switch later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mix them both. Use Apache for serving PHP and use nginx for static pages / images. 
Apache is more friendly configuration wise (htaccess, htpasswd, rewrite rules, etc), nginx is fast in regard to static assets.

Comment: How i can mix them both ?? Can you introduce an education to me ? tnx pal

Answer (score 1):

Nginx ...

Hell wordpress.com is using it ... :)

Here is some good data ... you may want to through varnish into the mix as well. http://www.garron.me/linux/apache-vs-nginx-php-fpm-varnish-apc-wordpress-performance.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I hope the link I provided (which is good benchamrking data) will give him some guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

Our sysadmins use nginx to serve the static content and apache to serve the other content. I'm not pretty sure how to create such setup, because I'm a developer only, but on our machines we're using both of them  at once.

Comment: That works like this: nginx serves all requests, but internally forwards all php requests to the apache server, that runs on another port (not 80). The user sees nothing of that, because nginx returns the page it gets from Apache.